# My function is changing an input variable how can I prevent or fix this?

Tags: python, list

> The for loop makes a list with 10 sub-lists with 10 values each. The WD() function is supposed to change values in the sub-lists and return the new list. The problem is that even with the return commented out, it changes the input variable DD. Why is it doing this and how can I prevent this from happening?

```
DD = []
for i in range(10):
   DD += [["  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  "]]

def WD(x, y, D, V): # x=sub list index  y=list index D=list V=replace with
    n = D[y-1]
    n[x-1] = V
    D[y-1] = n
    # return D

WD(5, 5, DD, "##")
print(DD)
```

> Here is the output

```
[['  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  '], ['  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  '], ['  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  '], ['  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  '], ['  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '##', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  '], ['  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  '], ['  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  '], ['  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  '], ['  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  '], ['  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ']]
```

Comment: What part of this is surprising to you? Mutating a mutable object changes the object itself, no matter where it's referenced from.

Comment: If you want to store your list in a way that doesn't let callees change it, use a tuple instead. Or pass the callee a _copy_ of the list instead of the original.

Comment: Either create a copy of the list D at the beginning of the function or send a copy in

Comment: Since you seem to find this behavior surprising, I suggesting reading https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`list` objects are mutable in Python, It means if you pass them to functions and edit that argument, the main list will be changed. For preventing this problem you can create a copy from the input list and pass that to the function

```
import copy

DD = []
for i in range(10):
   DD += [["  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  "]]

def WD(x, y, D, V): # x=sub list index  y=list index D=list V=replace with
    n = D[y-1]
    n[x-1] = V
    D[y-1] = n
    # return D

new_list = copy.deepcopy(DD)
WD(5, 5, new_list, "##")
print(DD)
```